# Stripe Fetch Subscription Data (ERROR: relation "subscriptions_stripecustomer" does not exist)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I'm getting this error.

> relation "subscriptions_stripecustomer" does not exist

I'm trying to configure Django Stripe Subscriptions following this manual https://testdriven.io/blog/django-stripe-subscriptions/

The code below is views.py which fetches subscription data.
It's following the above manual.

```
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from django.http.response import JsonResponse, HttpResponse  
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from subscriptions.models import StripeCustomer  

@login_required
def home(request):
    try:
        # Retrieve the subscription & product
        stripe_customer = StripeCustomer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(stripe_customer.stripeSubscriptionId)
        product = stripe.Product.retrieve(subscription.plan.product)

        # Feel free to fetch any additional data from 'subscription' or 'product'
        # https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object
        # https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/object

        return render(request, 'home.html', {
            'subscription': subscription,
            'product': product,
        })

    except StripeCustomer.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
    
@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request):
print("webhook page is opend")
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
endpoint_secret = settings.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
payload = request.body
sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
event = None


try:
    event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
    )
except ValueError as e:
    # Invalid payload
    return HttpResponse(status=400)
except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
    # Invalid signature
    return HttpResponse(status=400)

# Handle the checkout.session.completed event
if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
    session = event['data']['object']

    # Fetch all the required data from session
    client_reference_id = session.get('client_reference_id')
    stripe_customer_id = session.get('customer')
    stripe_subscription_id = session.get('subscription')

    # Get the user and create a new StripeCustomer
    user = User.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)
    StripeCustomer.objects.create(
        user=user,
        stripeCustomerId=stripe_customer_id,
        stripeSubscriptionId=stripe_subscription_id,
    )
    print(user.username + ' just subscribed.')

return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

The error might occurs at

**stripe_customer = StripeCustomer.objects.get(user=request.user)**

or

**user = User.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)**

because  I use custom user model "CustomUser"

My models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class StripeCustomer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripeCustomerId = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stripeSubscriptionId = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

accounts/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'CustomUser'
```

My settings.py

```
#used for django-allauth
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

In this situation, how should I change the below code proper way along with custom user model "CustomUser"?

**stripe_customer = StripeCustomer.objects.get(user=request.user)**

or

**user = User.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)**

or add some other code?

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Comment: Did you do the step in that blog post of "Finally run `migrate` to sync the database and runserver to start Django's local web server." ? The error here kind of sounds like the database wasn't initialised.

Comment: @karllekko Yes, I did.